# Qiskit function phase_amplitude_damping_error

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-operation, noise, kraus-representation

I am reading about the noise models that can be simulated in Qiskit and I found out the [phase_amplitude_damping_error](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.noise.phase_amplitude_damping_error.html) function. I read about it and it seems to be a function that simulates a combined dephasing and generalized amplitude damping channel (amplitude damping with finite temperature). I am pretty sure that the function implements such channel. However, I am wondering where do the Kraus operators that are described there come from (it is a Kraus rank 6 channel), as I have not been able to find any bibliography regarding such combined channel.